# Elastic Beanstalk Docker private registry with docker-compose

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Docker image from a private registry that is used for a team project.

A Docker-compose.yml is git-cloned by each team member to allow for ready-to-go config of volume, env and ports for the container.

```
version: '3'
services:
  webApp:
      image: my-private-registry/docker-app:latest
      ports:
        - 80:80
      volumes:
        - vendors:/var/www/app/vendor
        - ./var/logs/apache2:/var/log/apache2
volumes:
  vendors:
```

Now I wish to deploy that image/compose-file project to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but the platform can not access the private Docker registry **using the docker-compose file** ( image may require docker login error)

***Some info of what I've tried and noted so far***:
A] If the image is public the  docker-compose file ( which I just upload using the web console so far) does work, the image is pulled, a container is created and the app runs fine.
However if the image is private, it can not gain access, even after following the AWS instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html#docker-configuration.remote-repo).

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Authentication": {
    "bucket": "my-s3-bucket",
    "key": "config.json"
  },
}
```

and by reading the eb-engine.log, I can see that the first `docker-compose pull` works fine but then later on the final `docker-compose up` fails - triggering the error, as if the auth were lost along the way.

I know the docker-compose pull **works** because setting wrong auth in the config.json on the S3 Bucket triggers an error.

B] The auth and config works perfectly with a private docker image if I only use `Dockerrun.aws.json` instead of the `docker-compose` file.

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Authentication": {
    "bucket": "my-s3-bucket",
    "key": "config.json"
  },
  "Ports": [
     {
      "ContainerPort": 80,
      "HostPort": 80
     }
  ],
  "Image": {
     "Name": "my-private-registry/docker-app:latest",
     "Update": "true"
  },
  "Volumes" : [
    {
      "HostDirectory":"/var/app/current/var/logs/apache2",
      "ContainerDirectory":"/var/log/apache2"
    },
  ]
}
```

which is alright for testing purpose but forces us to depulicate any changes from docker-compose to it - since the compose file is used accross other non-AWS environnement, and will be less than ideal in the long run.

What am I missing ? Is there a mismatch in the config of my env with the docker-compose ?

Thanks

**Update 1**
By usins
 `sudo watch -n 1 -d cat /root/.docker/config.json`
I've been able to see that during the `docker-compose pull` the auth are present but
as soon as the `CleanEbExtensions` is launched, they're gone.

And this command is launched BEFORE dockler-compose is executed - and a `docker-compose down --rmi all` is executed in-between, nullifying the pull.

How come ?

**UPDATE**

Turns out it was an AWS Bug.
I've detailled step for a workaround in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well turns out it was a **bug on AWS side**.
I've found a very similar question

[AWS EB docker-compose deployment from private registry access forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66653185/aws-eb-docker-compose-deployment-from-private-registry-access-forbidden?noredirect=1#comment118673491_66653185)

the current solution was to employ the deploy hooks instead to either login do docker or copy the authfile.